# Load balanced multiple laravel app servers can not send email using smtp with gmail

Tags: laravel, load-balancing

Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)

Comment: Have you disabled Recaptcha in your gmail account which you are using ?? If not then do it with above link and try it do that and make ```hard refresh``` and ```optimize:clear``` and after this you can check your email will work

Answer (score 0):

add protocol and port number
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
and enable less secure app in google account

Comment: I've already done that, it's working in single server but not in multiple server thanks.